# Junit test that mocks System.in user input

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to create a Junit test that tests the output after user input. What I am currently trying is:

```
    @Before
    public void setStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(err));

    }

    @After
    public void restoreInitialStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
        System.setErr(originalErr);
    }
    @Test
    public void displayTest() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("X".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        System.out.println(sc.next());
        Assert.assertEquals("X", out.toString());
    }
```

But I am running into a problem where when I try to run the test it never finishes testing (loading animation). I am assuming that I am trying to mock the user input wrong but I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Scanner` is reading from the real `System.in` and not from the ByteArrayOutputStream because you create the `Scanner` before you update `System.in` It works like it is expected if you create the `Scanner` later.

```
@Test
public void displayTest() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("X".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    Assert.assertEquals("X", out.toString());
}
```

If you test code that interacts with `System.in`, `System.err` and `System.out` you may consider using [System Lambda](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-lambda) or [System Rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules). They help you with the setup code that you need for such tests and avoid common mistakes. Disclaimer: I'm the author of these libraries.